# Is it better to install Bitnami WordPress on physical or virtual machine?

Tags: wordpress, virtual-machine, bitnami, web-development-server

I need to start a WordPress website on a localhost environment on my Mac, and I later need to give access to my teammates to edit the website.
I did a little search on the net and found out that a pretty good option was using Bitnami. Now I would appreciate some advice on wether to install it in the physical machine or in a virtual machine, since both options are available and both seem good, but I can't really make my mind on which is better for my specific purposes (using a Mac and collaborating with others)... Thanks in advance

Comment: If you install it in a virtual machine then that virtual machine image would contain everything you need to run your wordpress website. This would make it easier to move it to new hardware or to the cloud later on if you decided you didn't just want it running on your local PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few pointers:

- I would always prefer installing a clean Wordpress as opposed to a Bitnami image.. Cleaner no unnecessary setups. But it depends on your skill level.
- While physical servers are always the best option, not everyone can afford them, as they are way more expensive. That is why there's the option to use virtual VPS or even shared hosting. Especially if the environment is not a Production one.
- If I am to install WP and I would later share it with a team, I would not install it on my local Mac or PC, but use virtual server or VPS for that. (as If I install WP on a local Mac, and I need to expose ports to the wild internet, I could potentially open other ports which are not meant to be open, via router's DMZ (for example), which could lead to security risks)